# Flutter Listen List Object When Any Item Value Change

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, flutter-material

i have an List item keeping bool values like that:
`List<bool> isSelectedDiscountValue = [false, false];`

```
 isSelectedDiscountValue.listen((selectedIndex)async {
  await _setValues(selectedIndex);
```

that code return to me **flutter the method listen is not defined for the type list** error.

i was listened any int or string values but its not possible on list.
i need listen this list cause when any value change i will some changes on ui.
but i can't listen to list.
how can i listen the list values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder
```

Comment: i want access to changed list on controller, how can i get changed data in valuenotifier on controller

Comment: If you define your list as ValueNotifier you can watch the changes live with ValueListenableBuilder